# PackageInstaller error when pragmatically updating app

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat, device-owner, cosu, packageinstaller

I have a class called `CosuUtils` that follows [this](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testdpc/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/afwsamples/testdpc/cosu/CosuUtils.java) class pretty closely. I am programmatically updating an application that is a device owner. This works fine in Android 6 but I'm getting the following error when trying to update in Android 7.

`PackageInstaller: Commit of session 1108510423 failed: /data/app/vmdl1108510423.tmp/COSU specified package com.mypackage inconsistent with com.mypackage.full`

In `CosuUtils` I set the package name as such

```
public static boolean installPackage(Context context, InputStream in, String packageName) throws IOException {
    PackageInstaller packageInstaller = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInstaller();
    PackageInstaller.SessionParams params = new PackageInstaller.SessionParams(PackageInstaller.SessionParams.MODE_FULL_INSTALL);
    params.setAppPackageName(packageName);
```

I was passing `com.mypackage` to `installPackage` which as mentioned earlier works fine on Android 6. This doesn't work in Android 7 unless I use `com.mypackage.full`. The issue is this breaks the ability for users who have upgraded to Android 7 to update to the latest version of the app. What changed between Android 6 and 7 that caused it to break and is there a work around for it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your issue has nothing to do with packageInstaller class - yet with flavor of your app. Are you sure that package-name stays the same for both Android 6 and 7?

Care to share build.gradle file?